# Enzyme's shallow().text() with React Native doesn't work as I expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mocha.js, enzyme

I'm trying to get some basic understanding around React Native tests w/[enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) and [react-native-mock](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-mock).

Not included below: A custom compiler for mocha to get the babel goodness.

My code is as follows:

`Block.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

export default ({title, ui}) => (
  <View>
    Title: {title}
  </View>
);
```

`Block.test.js`

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import {Block} from '../';
import React from 'react';

describe('<Block /> with props: title', () => {

  it('should have correct props', () => {
    expect(
      shallow(<Block title="Something" />).props()
    ).to.deep.equal( {title:"Something"} );
  });

  it('should have correct title', () => {
    expect(
      shallow(<Block title="Something" />).text()
    ).to.equal( "Something" );
  });

});
```

#### Test results

Mocha command:

```
mocha --compilers js:./test/support/compiler.js --require react-native-mock/mock --recursive **/test/*.test.js --watch
```

Mocha test results:

```
  <Block /> with props: title
    1) should have correct props
    2) should have correct title

  2 failing

  1) <Block /> with props: title should have correct props <Text />:

      AssertionError: expected { Object (children) } to equal { title: 'Something' }
      + expected - actual

       {
      -  "children": [
      -    "Title: "
      -    "Something"
      -  ]
      +  "title": "Something"
       }

      at Context.<anonymous> (components/test/Block.test.js:24:120)

  2) <Block /> with props: title should have correct title <Text />:

      AssertionError: expected '<View />' to equal 'Something'
      + expected - actual

      -<View />
      +Something

      at Context.<anonymous> (components/test/Block.test.js:28:119)
```

#### Unexpected behavior

1. `props()` seems to get the correct values, but in a different format than described by the api
2. `text()` doesnt render the nodes `textContent`, but instead, the stringified tag "`<View />`"

#### Alternative: props().children

Given the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default ({title, ui}) => (
  <View>
    <Text> The title...</Text>
    {title}
  </View>
);
```

`props().children` is the array `[<Text component instance>, "Something"]`

So the follow test passes:

```
  it('should have correct props', () => {
    expect(
      shallow(<Block title="Something" />).props().children
    ).to.contain( "Something" );
  });
```

#### Question

Why is Enzyme API behaving differently that described in the docs?

Specifically looking at the docs `shallow(<Block title="Something" />).text()` should equal *something* like: `The title...Something`

Am I doing something incorrect, or is it one the technologies I'm using?

### EDIT 1: Other problems

`html()`, `render()`, `update()` also don't seem to work with my setup

**EDIT: React native only works with `shallow` [at the moment](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/react-native.md)**

Comment: Just to be clear, mocha's `.to.equal` does a "triple equals" check, meaning two objects will not be `===` unless they are references to the same object in memory. Instead, use `.to.deep.equal` when comparing object.

Comment: Ah yes that would be misleading, I'll change that now

Comment: But yeah, there's no such thing as `shallow().text()` returning what's rendered. Instead always use `.props().children`.

Comment: @ZekeDroid I don't understand ^, as thats how I read the docs snippet `expect(shallow(<div><b>important</b></div>).text()).to.equal('important');` http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/text.html

Comment: Ah yeah but read just a bit above, and the example just below that one: `Returns a string of the rendered text of the current render tree. This function should be looked at with skepticism if being used to test what the actual HTML output of the component will be.` This only works if you don't have a React Component in there. As soon as you do, it will return the `.toString` method of the component, which is usually just the name.

Comment: Ah riiight. The docs could really do with the sentence you added on :D

Comment: haha yeah the library is still a little in its early stages and could use with more docs and examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution 1: A solution for `textContent`

From an Enzyme example app:

```
const title = "Blah";
const wrapper = shallow(<Block title={title} />);
expect(wrapper.length).to.equal(1);
expect(wrapper.contains(<Text>{title}</Text>)).to.equal(true);
```

### Solution 2: More semantic

Ok the more semantic version of **Alternative: props().children** above is below. This [Github discussion](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/445) also helped.

`Block.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default ({title, ui}) => (
  <View>
    <Text data={title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

`Block.test.js`:

```
  it('should have correct props', () => {
    const title = title;
    expect(
      shallow(<Block title={title} />)
         .find('Text') // Use selector to get certain children
         .first() // Get the first child
         .props() // Get its props
         .data
    ).to.equal(title)
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried solution 2 and it is working now. But I changed it to wrapper.find(Text).first().props().children

Comment: Solution 1 should use `.containsMatchingElement`,
`.contains` did not work for me and may be outdated for this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can reference the specific prop you would like to test:

   `expect(
     shallow(<Block title="Something" />).prop('title')
   ).to.equal( "Something" );`
2. [text()](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/text.html) is not doing what you are thinking here. Have a look at the second example in the docs, shallow won't render out your `<View>` tag

Comment: 1. Hm, that doesnt work either
2. Thats the thing, if you look at my output - it is _actually_ doing that. Which is of course, confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (very similar to `props().children`) is to access children in prop

```
  it('should have correct props', () => {
    expect(
      shallow(<Block title="Something" />).prop('children')
    ).toBe( "Something" );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ue `expect(wrapper.find(Foo).render().text()).to.equal('Hello World')` trick